# How to send decrpy of field value in Single Email Message

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, singleemailmessage

I have a input form in LWC(It's a salesforce Public Site). Once the Form submitted by the user , we will generate the Random Password and send Email to User with username and password using Email template.(Username is Email address)

**Password generator Logic**

```
Integer len = 10;
Blob blobKey = crypto.generateAesKey(128);
String key = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(blobKey);
string pwd = key.substring(0,len);
System.debug('************ '+pwd);
```

Right now I'm storing  the password as a plain text in my field.

My requirement is to store the encrypt password value in that field and in email send the decrypt value.
To achieve that, I'm using `Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV` to encrypt and storing in the field on sending email  i want to sent the decrypt value of that field. Now it's sending a encrypt value in the email.

Can you Please tell me how to achieve this. (I'm using Email template with `setWhatId`)

**Below code to encrpty and Decrypt the value**

```
//Data to encrypt
Blob data = Blob.valueOf(pwd);
//Generate an AES key for the encryption. 
Blob cryptoValue = Crypto.generateAesKey(256);
//Encrypt the data
Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', cryptoValue, data);
system.debug('encryptedData' + encryptedData );  
//Decrypt the data - the first 16 bytes contain the initialization vector
Blob decryptedData = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES256', cryptoValue, encryptedData);
//Get decrypted data 
String decryptedDataString = decryptedData.toString();
System.debug(decryptedDataString);
```

Comment: Sending user passwords over plaintext email is an _very bad_ idea. Credentials should never be transmitted over plaintext channels. (Or, ideally, at all).